# Avoiding race condition for inserting model to DB on complex conditions

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, race-condition, nosql

We are trying to create an algorithm/heuristic that will schedule a delivery at a certain time period, but there is definitely a race condition here, whereby two conflicting scheduled items could be written to the DB, because the write is not really atomic.

The only way to truly prevent race conditions is to create some atomic insert operation, TMK.

The server receives a request to schedule something for a certain time period, and the server has to check if that time period is still available before it writes the data to the DB. But in that time the server could get a similar request and end up writing conflicting data.

How to circumvent this? Is there some way to create some script in the DB itself that hooks into the write operation to make the whole thing atomic? By putting a locking mechanism on that script? What makes the whole thing non-atomic is the read and the wire time between the server and the DB.

Comment: It sounds like you're having problems making specific code work. In that case we can be more helpful if you post the [minimum code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: this question might belong on programmers.stackexchange?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I run into race condition I think of one immediate solution QUEUE.

Step 1) What you can do is that instead of adding data to a database directly you can add it to queue without checking anything.

Step 2) A separate reader will read from the queue check DB for any conflict and take necessary action.

This is one of the ways to solve this If you implement any better solution please do share it.

Hope that helps

Comment: thanks for the answer, I am actually not sure how this solves the problem. (1) Two workers in the same queue could get a similar request in a short period of time, (2) both workers could do a read from the DB, and see that a write was fine, (3) both workers write to a collection and effectively cause a high-level data conflict.

Comment: the only way to avoid the above, is if the write itself (3) is an atomic operation in the DB. the problem is the write in our DB is not atomic, it depends on more conditions than just a single field in the DB or what not.

Comment: can you describe more accurately how the queue will solve the problem? thanks!

Comment: I doubt you can have multiple reader, only one reader will read from the queue